# Jar dependencies error using Spark 2.3 structured streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I use spark2.3 structured streaming read Kafka 1.0 data exactly following the [documentation](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) and I get an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition`
```

The only kafka-related jar I used is `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.3.0.jar` as the doc said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to add this library in your project

> org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:0.10.0.0

maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0"
```

Solution found by the poster

> Adding kafka-clients:0.10.0.0.jar to HDFS instead of $SPARK_HOME/jars/

Comment: thanks, but still get this error. I put this jar in $SPARK_HOME/jars/

Comment: I now see in your comments that you have a maven project. Try adding the dependency like the others said.

Comment: Now I'm confused. Are you actually using maven, or just downloading the jars somewhere?
If you are downloading them, you should do what jayfah said, specifying all the needed jars with --packages.
Also maybe your SPARK_HOME is broken, so you should try manually specifying the jars with --jars /path/to/kafka-clients.jar, etc.

Comment: neither,I am using sbt and added all jars

Comment: So you are doing something like this: 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka-clients" % "0.10.0.0" and 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0"

With the second one, be careful with specifying the double percent "%%" instead of one. If you use just one, you must also append the scala version to the library, like this:
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11" % "2.3.0"

Comment: yes! yes!That's exactly what I did! However, still get this error......

Comment: In that case there could be a problem with your IDE or SBT (if you're using the console). Try running sbt commands like "sbt compile", "sbt update", "sbt inspect".

Comment: I figured it out, if I add kafka_client-xxx.jar to $SPARK_HOME/jars/, spark will load the jar,but will not find the class. And if I put kafka_client-xxx.jar onto hdfs, my program work fine...

Answer (score 0):

The class `TopicPartition` is missing, it is in this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

also a common issue is needing to add this option when running spark-submit:

`--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0`

Comment: I have this jar in my Environment, I tried your solution but not work

Comment: can you list your current spark dependencies into the question

Comment: you should also have:         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Even though it says in the document to add the dependency you already added, but probably you need to add the following dependency as well.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_KAFKA_VERSION</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>YOUR_SPARK_VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

It solved some of the issues I have.

PS: I know the second dependency is for Spark streams and not structured streaming but it's worth a try.